# Inheritance issue - expected '.' or '[' after super

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, inheritance

I'm new to Swift and XCode and I'm trying to make a simple game with a Player class that inherits from an Element class.

The setup is as follows:

Player.swift

```
class Player: Element {
    init(scene: SKScene) {
        super("player", categoryBitMask: PhysicsCategory.Player, contactBitMask: PhysicsCategory.Monster, scene: scene)
    }
}
```

Element.swift

```
class Element {

    let node: SKSpriteNode
    let scene: SKScene

    init(_ imageName: String, categoryBitMask: UInt32, contactBitMask: UInt32, scene: SKScene) {
        self.node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageName)
        self.scene = scene
    }
}
```

The error I get is in the Player class: Expected '.' or '[' after super. I don't understand this as super() is a valid method, so there's probably something fundamental I'm missing here?

[image: error image]

Comment: Aren't you just missing `.init` between `super` and `(`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `super.init`:

```
class Player: Element {
    init(scene: SKScene) {
        super.init("player", categoryBitMask: .Player, contactBitMask: .Monster, scene: scene)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rikh there's a 10 minute timer before you can accept SO questions